# Regex and numeric value to capture between two differents tags

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a script which help me to get new books from a website.

I'm working with preg_match_all. I have 7 informations to get : title, author, editor...

I've some problem to create my preg match mask. For example, I need the product code from here. There is between 3 and 10 code product to get on each page. :

```
<li><label>Réf : </label>21608</li>
```

At first I'm trying this :

```
$mask ="/Réf :(.*)<\/li>/Us";
```

It's work, but I want only the numbers. I'm searching on regex guides on the web, but I don't understand how to use the syntax for my goal, because this code product is not betweend two tags like that : `<open>...</open>`.  This code product have 4 or 5 numbers.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: If you're trying to parse XML/HTML, it's almost always a better idea to use an actual parser, rather than trying to use regex.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try step by step to match those digits:

1. We have `Réf`, let's make it `/réf/i` and use the `i` modifier to match case insensitive.
2. There is `space : space`, let's make it dynamic and match it with `\s*` which will match zero or more times whitespaces `/réf\s*:\s*/i`
3. We then have no digits at all, we may use `\D*` which will match everything except digits: `/réf\s*:\s*\D*/i`
4. We know that there is 4 to 5 digits, we'll use `\d{4,5}` which will match a digit 4 or 5 times : `/réf\s*:\s*\D*\d{4,5}/i`
5. We need only the digits, so let's put them into a group: `/réf\s*:\s*\D*(\d{4,5})/i`

---

**PHP code**

```
$string = '<li><label>Réf : </label>21608</li>';
preg_match_all('/réf\s*:\s*\D*(\d{4,5})/i', $string, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 21608
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following regular expression:

```
/Réf :\D*(\d+)<\/li>/
```

- `\D`: non-digit
- `\d`: digit

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
/>\s*(\d{3,10})\s*</
```